# Distribution of charge between three identical spheres

Tags: electrostatics, charge

The initial charges on the three identical metal spheres are the following: sphere $A$, $Q$;$B$, $-Q/4$; and sphere $C$, $Q/2$. Spheres $A$ and $B$ are fixed in place, with a center-to-center separation, which is much larger than the spheres. Spheres C is touched first to sphere A and then to sphere B and is then removed.

I know that when spheres $A$ and $C$ are touched we have to sum their charges and equally divide the charge of $3Q/4$ between then, since the spheres are equal and the total charge must be conserved. But I'm not sure what happens when spheres $B$ and $C$ are touched because of the negative charge, we should consider the charge of the sphere $B$ as $-Q/4$ or as the absolute value of the charge that is $Q/4$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say it yourself: The total charge is conserved in such a contact situation. That is, the total charge as a signed quantity, not its absolute value.

The most intuitive similar situation is when two spheres touch that have charge $q$ and $-q$. The result will be two neutral spheres because all the excess electrons from one sphere flow to the other one compensate the excess positive charge (i.e. lack of electrons).

Answer (score 0):

Since the spheres in this problem are identical in size, an important feature in such problems may be overlooked. Metal objects in electrical contact are at the **same electric potential.**

When the spheres (generally of different radii) are far from each other (as in this problem), it is easy to work out how the net-charge (the algebraic sum of the signed-charges) on the connected spheres distributes itself among them (of course, subject to the conservation of total charge).